# httpclient issue in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, httpclient

I am using System.Net.Http.HttpClient, 
It is showing some weird errors.Below is  my code.

```
public async static Task SearchYoutube(string query, int count)
{
    try
    {
        string format = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=20&q=mere&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&pageToken=";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        // System.Net.ServicePointManager.EnableDnsRoundRobin = true;
        var html = await client.GetStringAsync(format);
        string ht = html.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //var resp = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
    }
}
```

Exception-
The text associated with this error code could not be found.

An error occurred in the secure channel support.

My workarounds-
hrresult- -2147012739(I think this WINNETI_SCHANNEL_ERROR)

below is the stacktrace-

> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.d__86.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()

Steps I have taken to resolve the issue:

1.Turned off Firewall.

2.Given all available options in INTERNET OPTIONS(SSL,TLS etc.)

3.The link you have provided ,I have already checked that.

4.Tried Windows.Web.http instead of system.net.http

5.Used Handlers and Certificates

6.Checked capabilities-Internet(Client),Internet(Client and server) ,Private Networks(Even I checked all of the capabilities and tried but same result)

7.I have created a console application and pasted same codes,Worked like a charm.The only problem is ,it is not working in uwp platform and specifically in my system(It is working in my friend's system).

8.Tried all available option available in internet.

Comment: What Windows and Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello-I am using windows 10,Windows 10 sdk 14393,Visual studio 2015 community version.

Comment: I am also having issues with another url, I used this for workaround https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient and mine is working now.

Comment: Nope..This is not working for me.Already tried.Thing is the code working for console application not in uwp.

Comment: I tested with the code you've posted and it works well in my side. `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` can be used in UWP apps and there is no wrong in your code. I'd suggest you test with other devices. Also you can use Fiddler to trace the https traffic to help debugging.

Comment: So hitting the same API on Internet Explorer in your system would be showing

> Make sure you’ve got the right web address: https://www.googleapis.com... Its probably an IE version related issue. The same link would work in InPrivate mode of IE. Might be Microsoft will fix it later on.

Comment: For me it worked AFTER going to `API Manager` and for your credential, under **Accept requests from these server IP addresses** add your IP address.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT-As I have mentioned ..It is working in other uwp machines,It is not working in my machine only

Comment: @jstreet-I dont think ,your solution will be a good option,because,if it is a genuine issue,then it will not work for other users..As If i mention ip address..

Comment: @uncle_scrooge : Yes, it could potentially be a good solution for other users too if they enter their specific IP address for their specific API key in their specific accounts. The particular IP address in itself does not matter, and obviously you don't need to mention it, but only the fact that this information might be missing and you should provide it. Note that you say it works in other machines but not in your particular machine only. So it sounds like this could be precisely the problem here. Just **try it**, you never know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not enough rep to comment; **Ivan Ičin** likely correct if you are using the Windows Insider Fast Ring build, the secure connection will have problems with Google servers. This has been fixed in their latest release, Build 15025, that came out today (Feb. 1, 2016).

Release Note:

> Windows Insiders should no longer have trouble connecting to certain
>   Google sites due to an implementation of a new security model being
>   rolled out to further enhance user security.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer..You are true..I just updated my insider preview to 15025..And now all working fine..Thanks again..

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using Windows Insider builds. Google sites don't work in Insider builds because of the current security policies that will be fixed. You can read the text for Edge here: https://mspoweruser.com/cant-access-youtube-gmail-insider-builds-microsoft-working/ but the same goes to HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer..You are true..I just updated my insider preview to 15025..And now all working fine..I don't know how to divide my bounty points.I am sorry I am accepting below flamewave000's answer as he has less points..Thanks a lot again...